# Button to open link in new tab

Tags: javascript, html, button, web

I am making a website and I want a new tab to open at a specific address when I click a button.

This is the html for my button:

```
<button id="AsDownload" onclick="AsDownload();">Download</button>
```

And this is my javascript:

```
function AsDownload(){
    chrome.tabs.create({url:"https://alexanderhawking.itch.io/asteroid-racer"});
};
```

But it is not working and I can't figure out why, can someone help me?

Comment: Why not use an `a` tag? `<a href="https://alexanderhawking.itch.io/asteroid-racer" target="_blank">Download</a>`

Comment: I would like it to be button

Comment: `a` tag is the correct semantic element to use for this behaviour, you can style it as a button

Comment: Ok cool, I'll give it a go

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to the other answers, add **"_blank"** to open in a new tab if you intend on using a `JavaScript` function.

```js
function AsDownload() {
  //window.open(pathString, target);
  window.open("https://alexanderhawking.itch.io/asteroid-racer", "_blank");
};
```

```html
<button id="AsDownload" onclick="AsDownload()">Download</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use window.open() to do that.

```
<input type="button" value="button name" onclick="window.open('http://www.website.com')" />
```

Your example:

```
function AsDownload() {
  window.open("https://alexanderhawking.itch.io/asteroid-racer", "_blank");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try **window.open()** ? It opens URL in new tab.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want it to be a button rather than an anchor tag `<a>` use this in your function:

```
window.open("https://alexanderhawking.itch.io/asteroid-racer");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can integrate a link and a button like that

```
  <button id="AsDownload"><a href="https://alexanderhawking.itch.io/asteroid-racer/"target="_blank">load</a></button>
```

this would open up in a new tab